# how to use checkbox in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I want to diaplay if the checkbox is checked or not

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm">
Languages:
<input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="check">telugu
<input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="check1">Hindi
<span ng-show="frm.check.$dirty && frm.check.$error.ng-checked">not-checked</span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the checkbox is not selected or not checked then it should display that checkbox is not clicked

Answer (score 1):

First, if you checkbox is not checked initially, it won't be in `dirty` state until user changes it. But, if you want to show the span anyway, better use this.

```
<span ng-show='check==false'>Not Checked</span>
```